# Задача в конце главы про функции с++

Tags: c++, функции

Вот собственно задание: Напишите функцию, которая обычно принимает один аргумент — адрес строки - и выводит эту строку один раз. Однако если задан второй аргумент типа `int`, не равный нулю, то эта функция выводит строку столько раз, сколько было осущест­влено вызовов этой функции к моменту ее данного вызова. (Обратите внимание, что количество выводимых строк *не равно значению второго аргумента*, оно *равно числу вызовов функции к моменту последнего вызова*.)

Действительно, это не слишком полезная функция, но она заставит применить некоторые из методов, рассмотренных в данной главе. Напишите простую программу для де­монстрации этой функции.

В данной главе рассматривались: Встроенные функции, Ссылочные переменные, Передача функции аргументов по ссылке, Аргументы по умолчанию, Перегрузка функций, Шаблоны функций, Спецификации шаблонов функций.

Вот, что я смог написать, знаю что не правильно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить.

```
#include <iostream>

void out(char* a);
void out(char *a, int n);

int n = 0;

int main()
{
    char ch[] = "Hello";
    char * pd = ch;
    out(pd);
    out(pd);
    out(pd);
    out(pd);
    out(pd);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    out(pd, n);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void out(char *a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    n++;
}

void out(char *a, int n)
{
    if (n != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как по мне, проще всего сделать так, как показано ниже. Статическая переменная `n` подсчитывает количество вызовов, второй аргумент имеет значение по умолчанию 0...

```
void out(const char* a, int x = 0)
{
    static int n = 0;
    ++n;
    cout << a << endl;
    if (x)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
            cout << a << endl;
    }
}
```

Правда, эта функция считает и текущий вызов. Но если это не надо делать - то просто перенесите `++n` в конец функции.